# Is there a combat log in Heroes of the Storm?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I realized that I could've answered [my own question just now](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/212835/11084) if I had access to some sort of combat log. So I [Googled](https://www.google.nl/search?q=HotS%20is%20there%20a%20combat%20log) and I [Binged](http://www.bing.com/search?q=HotS%20is%20there%20a%20combat%20log), but found only [a forum post](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/12506151492) that implies there isn't one. However, it also shows the problem of forums: it is dated July 2014, so the info might well be outdated without OP or mods being able to update the posts.

What I've also tried: going through all the Hotkeys to find a related option. The only related one seems to be "Observer > Toggle the Console": <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>. However, in "Try" mode nor when watching a replay did that command do anything at all for me.

The existence of [hotslogs.com](https://www.hotslogs.com/) suggests replays *do* contain at least some statistics. Perhaps you can view the combat log when opening a replay?

**Is there a combat log in HotS?**

Comment: I never opened a combat log file using a text editor, but you could try it and see what's in there

Comment: @Huangism Where can you find those files?

Comment: I forgot exactly where they are at as I am at work and unable to check, but you could probably google it. I think it's in Documents or my games or something like that. Or try looking in the HOTS folder under replays, I don't remember but if you look around, you should be able to find them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no combat log right now. HOTS Logs relies on users to upload their replay files. There's only Win/Loss and game time. There's no logging of kill at X location or at X time or anything that we know of yet.